# Requesting intraday historical data via Bloomberg API in python

Tags: python, excel, api, bloomberg

I'm wondering if anyone has been able to use the Bloomberg API within python to pull a piece of intraday historical data for a specific time. There are threads about pulling intraday data for given intervals (5,10,15 minute) but I'm looking to reference a specific time and date (e.g. 01/09/19 13:33:42) and pull the data at that time.

This is possible in excel via a formula with overrides like this:

BDH("AAPL US EQUITY","BID",(DATE + TIME)-0.01,(DATE + 
TIME)-0.0001,"IntrRw=True","points=1","SIZE=S","TYPE=H","DTS=H","TimeZone=new York","cols=2;rows=1")

Appreciate any thoughts or ideas.

I've been trying to use the xbbg on a simple data request just to figure out the syntax with no luck. Below is the date/time format I have when running this in excel but have no luck. Tried with all overrides in the above excel formula but no luck.

```
from xbbg import blp
SPXLAST = blp.bdh(tickers='SPX INDEX',flds='PX_LAST',start_date='09-26-18 
14:30:25',end_date='09-26-18 14:30:25',TimeZone='New York')
print(SPXLAST)
```

Have been able to pull only EOD data but nothing for a specific intraday time.

Comment: To retrieve intraday bars, you probably need `blp.bdib` - see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283556/python-bloomberg-api-pdblp-intraday-request or look at the library docs.

Comment: It’s about timezone: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53504904/1332656

Answer (score 1):

The blpapi is supported in Python. Here is a code snippet:

```
def sendIntradayTickRequest(session, options, identity = None):
refDataService = session.getService("//blp/refdata")
request = refDataService.createRequest("IntradayTickRequest")

# only one security/eventType per request
request.set("security", "IBM US Equity")

# Add fields to request
eventTypes = request.getElement("eventTypes")
eventTypes.appendValue("TRADE")
eventTypes.appendValue("BID")
eventTypes.appendValue("ASK")
# add more tick types

# All times are in GMT
request.set("startDateTime", "2019-01-15T14:40:00")
request.set("endDateTime", "2019-01-15T14:43:00")

# options
request.set("includeConditionCodes", True)
# add more optionals

print("Sending Request:", request)
session.sendRequest(request)
```

Comment: Hi Mourad, thanks for the response. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here but this is the output I receive when I run that bit of code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\BBG API\bloomytest4.py", line 9, in <module>
    request.set("security", "IBM US Equity")
AttributeError: module 'request' has no attribute 'set'

Comment: This is only a snippet, not a complete code. It requires the blpapi package to be installed first. Next create a session, open the service, etc.

Here is a complete code sample https://gist.github.com/jfujino/5856269