# query bloomberg api with python; tickers return nothing

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi, pdblp

I'm new to bloomberg terminals but I'm trying to pull data from bloomberg using the python API. The underlying c++ SDK seems to be working as I have pip installed the following python libraries:

```
blpapi
pdblp
```

I can connect to the terminal and run the example data that comes with the packages:

```
con = pdblp.BCon(debug=False, port=8194, timeout=5000)
con.start()
# print some data
con.bdh('SPY US Equity', ['PX_LAST', 'VOLUME'],'20150629', '20150630')
```

This returns the following:

```
ticker     SPY US Equity
field            PX_LAST       VOLUME
date
2015-06-29        205.42  202621332.0
2015-06-30        205.85  182925106.0
```

So everything seems to be working. The problem is if I want to try searching certain tickers it just returns an empty datafame:

```
con.bsrch('COH9')  #returns []
con.bsrch("COMDTY:COH9") 
con.bsrch('COH9 Comdty')
con.bsrch("COMDTY")
con.bsrch('CL1 Comdty')
con.bsrch('CO1 Comdty')
```

All of these return []. the 'bsrch' method should work because the following example provided in the readme works and fetches data:

```
con.bsrch("COMDTY:NGFLOW")
```

The issue is that each of these strings returns something in the bloomberg terminal yet returns nothing with this api. why? The docs say this is a search function?

I've tried other commands such as:

```
con.bdib('CL1 Comdty', start_datetime='20190127', end_datetime='20190128', event_type='BID', interval=1)
```

which also throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bloomberg_api_test.py", line 56, in <module>
    bloomberg_api_test()
  File "bloomberg_api_test.py", line 38, in bloomberg_api_test
    print(con.bdib('CL1 Comdty', start_datetime='20190127', end_datetime='20190128', event_type='BID', interval=1))
  File "C:\Users\svc_tradingops\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pdblp\pdblp.py", line 681, in bdib
    data = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('time').sort_index().loc[:, flds]
  File "C:\Users\svc_tradingops\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4156, in set_index
    raise KeyError('{}'.format(missing))
KeyError: "['time']"
```

There doesn't seem to be much clear guidance in the docs about how to use these methods unless there is something I missed?

Comment: for intraday queries: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53504904/1332656

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly the `bsrch` is not a very well documented feature of the library. One of the issues around this is that `bsrch` uses makes an `ExcelGetGridRequest` via the underlying `blpapi` library and this service is not documented by Bloomberg. As of the last time I checked there is no information in the `Services & schemas reference guide` or the `Core developer guide` from Bloomberg about an `ExcelGetGridRequest`. One way to figure out if this is an issue with the underlying `blpapi` service or some handling via `pdblp` is to set `debug=True`, which will print the underlying response messages. e.g.

```
import pdblp
con = pdblp.BCon(debug=True).start()
con.bsrch("COMDTY:COH9")
```

The message below seems to indicate this is an invalid domain. As mentioned above there is not much documentation on what this means since the `ExcelGetGridRequest` service is not well documented but Bloomberg support may be able to shed more light on this service.

```
pdblp.pdblp:INFO:Sending Request:
ExcelGetGridRequest = {
    Domain = "COMDTY:COH9"
}

pdblp.pdblp:INFO:Event Type: 'RESPONSE'
pdblp.pdblp:INFO:Message Received:
GridResponse = {
    NumOfFields = 0
    NumOfRecords = 0
    ColumnTitles[] = {
    }
    DataRecords[] = {
    }
    ReachMax = false
    Error = "The domain entered: COMDTY:COH9 is not valid."
    SequenceNumber = 0
}
```

For `bdib`, as per the docstrings the `start_datetime` and `end_datetime` format should be `YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS`, but admittedly the error that is raised when this is not satisfied is a bit misleading. For example

```
con.bdib('CL1 Comdty', start_datetime='2019-01-28T10:00:00', 
         end_datetime='2019-01-28T10:05:00', event_type='BID', interval=1)

                      open   high    low  close  volume  numEvents
time                                                              
2019-01-28 10:00:00  52.62  52.67  52.62  52.66   10147        700
2019-01-28 10:01:00  52.66  52.69  52.64  52.69    9181        608
2019-01-28 10:02:00  52.69  52.70  52.68  52.69   12349        732
2019-01-28 10:03:00  52.69  52.71  52.68  52.70   11816        631
2019-01-28 10:04:00  52.70  52.70  52.67  52.69    8629        523
```

Comment: Thanks, its helpful to see a working example of con.bdib. Would you happen to know how to get con.bdh to return all fields for a given ticker without specifically naming them? The docs don't seem to mention this either. For example I'm interested in the 'Inventory' field of 'CGIEEUST' but if I try con.bdh('CGIEEUST Index', ['INDEX'], '20190101', '20190205') another cryptic error comes up. I'm happy to post this as a separate question?

Comment: This is not how the underlying `HistoricalDataRequest` API exposed by bloomberg works, desired fields must be explicitly queried. I'm unsure if there is a programmatic way to query a ticker for all relevant fields as I have never come across this specific use case. I think your best bet would be to inquire directly with bloomberg help to first see if this is even supported on their end.

Comment: Sorry about the newbie question, thanks again for your help