# Retrieve intraday data with BDH() using blpapiwrapper in Python

Tags: python, blpapi

I'm trying to get the stock price at a specific time using the blpapiwrapper (https://github.com/alex314159/blpapiwrapper) with inspiration from this (https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/35126/price-at-specific-time-from-bloomberg):

```
=BDH("EURGBP Curncy","Last Price","7/13/2017 3:00:00 PM","7/13/2017 3:00:01 PM","BarTp=T,BarSz=1,Fill=P")
```

If I try to recreate it, I get the EOD price instead of the last price between 15:40:00 and 15:40:01. Using the same syntax in Excel with same SEDOL and dates gives the correct stock price at 15:40.

```
bloomberg = BLP()

startdate = datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-01-03 15:40:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
enddate = datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-01-03 15:40:01', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

bloomberg.bdh('/SEDOL1/B151P43 Equity', "Last price",startdate, enddate , "BarTp = T, BarSz = 1, Fill = P")
```

I've tried to modify the bdh() function in blpapiwrapper changing periodicity to 'INTRADAY' and including '%H:%M:%S' in the definition of 'startDate' and 'endDate' but without luck.

```
def bdh(self, strSecurity='SPX Index', strData='PX_LAST', startdate=datetime.date(2014, 1, 1),
        enddate=datetime.date(2014, 1, 9), adjustmentSplit=False, periodicity='DAILY'):
    request = self.refDataSvc.createRequest('HistoricalDataRequest')
    request.append('securities', strSecurity)
    if type(strData) == str:
        strData = [strData]

    for strD in strData:
        request.append('fields', strD)

    request.set('startDate', startdate.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
    request.set('endDate', enddate.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
    request.set('adjustmentSplit', 'TRUE' if adjustmentSplit else 'FALSE')
    request.set('periodicitySelection', periodicity)
    requestID = self.session.sendRequest(request)
```

Any suggestions for a solution using blpapiwrapper?

Comment: To retrieve intraday data, you would need to issue an `IntradayBarRequest` or an `IntradayTickRequest` to the API which don't seem to be implemented by the library you are using. I don't use Python so can't recommend one but there must be an alternative lib that also covers intraday requests.

Comment: This one for example seems to allow you to do that: https://github.com/matthewgilbert/pdblp - and there's a question with examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283556/python-bloomberg-api-pdblp-intraday-request