# Tick data Bloomberg

Tags: bloomberg, blpapi, pdblp

I am trying to extract tick data of NQH0 Index using pdblp. How should I change the code below to get data by minutes and seconds..

```
import pdblp
con = pdblp.BCon().start()
con.bdh("NQH0 Index", "PX_LAST", "20140604", "20140610")
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283556/python-bloomberg-api-pdblp-intraday-request

Comment: thanks for the link, will it work for Indices futures?

Comment: does  blp.bdib  work for Indices?