# blpapi IntradayTickRequest python

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi, pdblp

I am using the `pdblp` Python wrapper to query historical daily data from Bloomberg.
Based on the package documentation and the post in [Python Bloomberg API pdblp intraday request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283556/python-bloomberg-api-pdblp-intraday-request)  it is not possible to use the pdblp package to query intraday data.

One answer in the above link suggested to use blpapi API directly via the below:

```
def sendIntradayTickRequest(session, options):
refDataService = session.getService("//blp/refdata")
request = refDataService.createRequest("IntradayTickRequest")

# only one security/eventType per request
request.set("security", options.security)

# Add fields to request
eventTypes = request.getElement("eventTypes")
for event in options.events:
    eventTypes.appendValue(event)

# All times are in GMT
if not options.startDateTime or not options.endDateTime:
    tradedOn = getPreviousTradingDate()
    if tradedOn:
        startTime = datetime.datetime.combine(tradedOn,
                                              datetime.time(15, 30))
        request.set("startDateTime", startTime)
        endTime = datetime.datetime.combine(tradedOn,
                                            datetime.time(15, 35))
        request.set("endDateTime", endTime)
else:
    if options.startDateTime and options.endDateTime:
        request.set("startDateTime", options.startDateTime)
        request.set("endDateTime", options.endDateTime)

if options.conditionCodes:
    request.set("includeConditionCodes", True)

print "Sending Request:", request
session.sendRequest(request)
```

I am not familiar with the underlying API and struggle to make sense of the `session` and `options` objects provided as arguments in the function call. Can someone please provide a simple example on how to use this function to retrieve intraday data?
(I am not referring to OHLC data, which can be queried using the `bdib()` function in `pdblp`)

Comment: The xbbg package has a blp.bdtick() function.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a session object with the blpapi package.

```
s_options = blpapi.SessionOptions()
s_options.setServerHost('localhost')
s_options.setServerPort(8194)
s_options.setAutoRestartOnDisconnection(True)

session = blpapi.Session(s_options)
```

You can also pass a function to your session, which gets called for each event that the session returns. Then the session object looks like this:

```
session = blpapi.Session(s_options, process_event)
```

The response function needs two arguments, event and session:

```
def process_event(self, event, session):
    for msg in event:
        print(msg)
```